# Catch a string and transmit it to a Javascript function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, jquery-events

Below is Django template language syntax. But that doesn't matter.
{{  }} means something transmitted from the framework.

In the backend I have two related models. That may be person and their addresses. One-to-many relationship. So, one person has many addresses.

Well, in the page with detail information about the person I render a list of their addresses. And for each address on the right are two buttons: edit and delete. Update via AJAX of course.

How to edit and delete is a mystery to me. Let's focus on edit as an example.

This is part of detail information about the model.

```
<ul id="{{ related_model_name }}_ul" class="update">
    {% for object in object_list %}
        <li>{{ object }}
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Edit</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

What do we have here: 
1. {{ object }} will render just a string. Like "Buckingham Palace
London SW1A 1AA". So, it is not clickable, but "Edit" is clickable.

2. The framework can generate update url for this object like this {{ object.get_update_url }}, which will result in something like **'person/12/update_address/'. I would like to catch this update url via Javascript on click event**. And then I will be able to transmit it via AJAX to the server.
3. Then I am going to act like this:

> ```
> function update_address(url){
>         $.ajax({
>             method: 'get',
>             url: url,
>             success: show_address_form_get,
>             error: fail
>         });
> }
> ```

```
function handle_update_buttons(){
    var update_button_list = $(".update");
    $.each(update_button_list, function assign_click(){
        this.click(update_date);
    })
}
```

Well, this is my rough idea. A newbie in web development. Maybe there is a simpler way.

Could you give me a hint how to transmit for each address its update url to the update_date function on clicking the corresponding Edit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to assign a `data-attribute`, like `data-updateUrl` to the link:

```
<ul id="{{ related_model_name }}_ul" class="update">
    {% for object in object_list %}
        <li>{{ object }}
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-updateUrl="{{ object.get_update_url }}">Edit</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can then take that attribute to your function (in your click handler)

```
function clicked(el) {
    var updateUrl = el.target.getAttribute('data-updateUrl');
}
```

Comment: Looks very promising. I need some time to try. If everything is good, I'll be very much thankful to you.